# How do i pass a string to setContentView()?

Tags: android, string, variables, setcontentview

My app has a method that uses

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_deashibarai);`

to set the view of the activity.

But i would like that the xml file name (in this case, activity_deashibarai) to be passed as a variable.
I have a string variable to store that variable.

`setContentView(R.layout.variable)`   does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This Solved it.

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String xmlfile = null;
    if (extras != null) {
        xmlfile = extras.getString("xmlfile");
    }


    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(xmlfile, "layout", getPackageName());
    setContentView(id);
```